# Configure Apache as reverse proxy and tomcat over https

Tags: apache, tomcat, https, reverse-proxy

Is there any issues if I configure apache reverse proxy with https which will communicate with tomcat over again https.

e.g

Browser-> HTTPS -> Apache -> HTTPS-> Tomcat

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*any issue* as in "anything else but additional setup requirements, more performance issues and more things to break"? I can't think of some, but refuse to give a blank "pass" to go with this.

You'll have to argue for what you want to achieve. If you can't trust the connection between Apache and Tomat (e.g. network, routers) https is a way to utilize this mistrust. On the other hand, you'll introduce many points of failures. Like: Certificates expiring without being obvious (e.g. tomcat's certificate will never be shown to the client), Apache will be required to trust the signer of tomcat's certificate etc.

If you can't trust your network, evaluate all the options: VPN between Apache and tomcat might be another solution to validate: Once this is established, you basically only have one encryption configuration to set up - not the repeated handshakes that appear on https. This might be an option if higher performance is required.

I hope the hints help - for completeness, the general the answer (or counter-question) to your question is: "What problem do you want to solve?"

Comment: Basically I am using apache front end with https to connect my tomcat backend. Both are installed in same server. Now I need to move tomcat back end to different server. So I need to secure communication between apache and tomcat secure while preserving current apache front end set up.